# Cannot connect to MySQL database from OVH server

Tags: mysql, flutter, ovh

I cannot connect to my database which is hosted on OVH remotely from Flutter's package mysql1 and get the following error:

> flutter: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'saintlouqpweb.mysql.db'
> (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

I usually access it through phpMyAdmin where I have three fields to fill: the server, the user, and the password. I use exactly the same values than there with mysql1 on Flutter in addition to the database name (the server field of phpMyAdmin being the host field of mysql1).

I have searched for hours a solution but I still find nothing on this forum and on the web. Everything is always brought back to a 'localhost' server or a problem too different from mine.

Here is the piece of code causing the error :

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async
  {
    try {
      final conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
        host: 'saintlouqpweb.mysql.db', // the exact server name entered on phpMyAdmin
        user: 'myusername',
        password: '*********',
        db: 'mydatabasename',
      ));

    var results = await conn.query(
      'SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE ID=1;'
    );

    return results.toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }
```

I would be grateful if someone can help me about that or experienced the same issue previously.

Comment: `saintlouqpweb.mysql.db` doesn't look like a valid hostname.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well it is the hostname I enter when connecting to phpMyAdmin...

Comment: @MianalaLoharano it appears to be impossible with OVH to access their db remotely for security reasons... did you try the answer from Brugere below ?

Comment: @ventatto there has to be a solution, how can we not connect to our own database?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hostname it looks like you have a shared SQL database. According to [this OVH community post](https://community.ovh.com/en/t/allow-remote-connections-on-the-mysql/557/2) remote connections are not allowed.

Comment: Well indeed this is the database of my website so it is web hosting I suppose. Still looking for a solution but I think it won't be possible with OVH...

Comment: @ventatto You need to order separate database service (OVH Cloud DB).

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful, and well buried :-) I don't think their doc. discusses this, for obvious reasons (they are pushing for more expensive services).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mark Rotteveel in comment, the host you provided in code sample does not look valid.

You can find you host address in your OVHcloud manager : https://www.ovh.com/manager/web

It is accessible inside `Web Cloud`->`Databases` and in the table `General Informations`

Comment: Ok thanks for this suggestion, the admin of the database told me it was normal the access was forbidden (for security reasons), but I will show him your answer